# conflict between guake and ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu-mate, guake

I have installed Xubuntu 16.04. Then I gave a try to use Ubuntu Mate, installed appropriate packages for it. After installation, I logged out and logged in again with Mate session. Everything was fine until I launched Guake terminal. It warned me to change activation key to other than `F12`. On the other hand, when I activate (or open) Guake, the bottom bar of it was missing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing. It was "tilda", another dropdown terminal app, which was conflicting with guake. When I hit "preferences" on right-click menu, preferences of tilda were shown. At this time, guake hadn't launched. I have recognized the "conflict of conflict" after I asked the question above.

Sorry again!